# Pandas how can I dropping rows by multiple conditions or from a defined variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem in python pandas.

My Excel file input is:

```
TEAM
001
001
002
003
004
```

I want to improve my coding, how can I drop `TEAM` `001, 002, ...` in one command or how can I define a variable
`dropteam = '001','002'` to delete 001 and 002?

Like this the but this code is wrong
`dropteam001 = replacename[~replacename['TEAM'].str.contains(dropteam)`]

My code:

```
dropteam001 = replacename[~replacename['TEAM'].str.contains('001')]
dropteam002 = dropteam001[~replacename['TEAM'].str.contains('002')]
```

Comment: Did either of these solutions answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two in one time

```
dropteam = replacename[~replacename['TEAM'].str.contains('001|002')]
```

Comment: Thank You , i use `dropteam = '001|002'
dropdata1=repalcename[~repalcename['TEAM'].str.contains(dropteam )]`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of the items you want to drop and do:

```
dropteam001 = replacename[~replacename['TEAM'].isin(newlist)]
```